# How to save to a list every input I receive from the same html form?

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

how can I save to a list every input I receive from the same form?
How would like to save in the list every weight the user input.
Is it possible to save all the weights the user insert? Also if he reloads the page?

This is the form:

```
<form action="/send" method="POST">
    <label for="">Weight</label>
    <input type="text" name="weight">
    <label for="">Height</label>
    <input type="text" name="height">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <br>

<div class="alert">
    {{ BMI }}
</div>
```

And this is the flask app:

```
   from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
   import schedule


   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

   @app.route('/send', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def send():
    if request.method=='POST':
        weight = request.form['weight']
        height = request.form['height']
        a = float(weight)
        b = float(height)
        BMI = a/(b**2)
        weights = []
        weights.append(weight)
        return render_template('index.html', BMI=BMI, weights = weights)
```

Comment: Your route is broken. That will crash on every GET request because you don't `return` anything

Comment: Everything inside view will vanish once return. What you want is some kind of database to store value and then return to `index.html`

Comment: You either need a database or you need to use the `session` object to persist data

Comment: I return the BMI calculation.

Comment: Not on a GET request you don't

Comment: What should I do for the routing problem?

Comment: your list now has function scope, it is reinitialised everytime with the method, change the list's scope

Comment: @Petronella no, really, don't do that. Do not have variable globals in a web server

Comment: @roganjosh the best option is to use database right?

Comment: It's not possible to say what the best option is without knowing the full use case. If this is just a toy program and you're happy for previous data to be lost once the session ends, then a database might be overkill

Answer (score 0):

You need something to persist this data between requests. If you only need it for a short period of time, you can just use a `session`. The docs for [`Flask-Session`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) appear to show it being imported from `flask.ext.session` now, but my version is imported as `from flask_session import Session`.

Below is a minimal but complete toy example to show how this works (in this case I just store BMI but you can store multiple lists in the session dict). Note that, if you use the default session that comes with Flask, its storage capacity is very small; this is why I'm persisting session data to a file.

If you need the data to persist for longer (i.e. permanently) then you'll need to use a database. A point of note: *twice* people have advocated storing this data in a global variable. This is terrible for a web app because multiple users will start trampling over each others' data, not to mention that multiple processes will start getting out of sync.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, request, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)

homepage_template = """
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('bmi_submission') }}" id="bmi_form">
Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" value=""><br>
Height: <input type="text" name="height" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="result_div"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $("#bmi_form").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $(this);
       var url = form.attr('action');

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(),
           context: form,
           success: function(resp) {
               $("#result_div").html(resp); 
           }
       });
   });
</script>
"""

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def homepage():
    return render_template_string(homepage_template)


@app.route('/calc_bmi', methods=['POST'])
def bmi_submission():
    weight = request.form.get('weight')
    height = request.form.get('height')
    a = float(weight)
    b = float(height)
    BMI = a/(b**2)

    if session.get('bmi'):
        session['bmi'].append(BMI)
    else:
        session['bmi'] = [BMI]

    return '<br>'.join([str(item) for item in session['bmi']])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the database.